# What accuracy function is used in Keras when using metrics=['accuracy']?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'd like to know what accuracy function is used when using `metrics=['accuracy']`:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I saw [keras/metrics.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py) file. There are `some_accuracy` functions in that file. But I couldn't find `accuracy`. Where can I see the source code and how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate accuracy function [is inferred automatically from the loss function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5b6243485acc20cc36f2db4f258512c332d691ec/keras/engine/training.py#L374) you have used. As you have mentioned, the accuracy functions has been defined in [metric.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py) file:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)


def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
                  K.floatx())


def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    # flatten y_true in case it's in shape (num_samples, 1) instead of (num_samples,)
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.flatten(y_true),
                          K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
                          K.floatx())
```

- `binary_accuracy` is used when the dimension of the last axis of output of the model is equal to one (i.e. `(..., 1)`) or the `binary_crossentropy` is used as loss.
- `sparse_categorical_accuracy` is used when `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used as the loss function.
- Finally, `categorical_accuracy` is used when `categorical_crossentropy` has been set as the loss function.

Also, note that the `accuracy` metric is only valid for classification tasks. Therefore, if you use `accuarcy` as the metric in a regression tasks, the reported metric values may not be valid at all.

Further, there are two other built-in accuracy functions as well:

```
def top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)


def sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.cast(K.max(y_true, axis=-1), 'int32'), k), axis=-1)
```

To use them, you need to explicitly pass their names to `metrics` argument, i.e. `metrics=['top_k_categorical_accuracy']` or `metrics=['sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy']`

Comment: I got 'accuracy' is built in "keras/engine/training.py"